# Insert date into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, datepicker

My website is simple, all I want to do is insert a date that I chose in a date picker into MySQL. (at the moment its inserting like this "0000-00-00 00:00:00").

My PHP/HTML code is:

```
<form id="form_351400" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="insert.php">
    <div class="form_description">
        <div style="width:100%;border:0px solid #000;">
            <div style="float:left; width:75%;">

                <h2 align="left">Samurai Digital d.o.o.</h2>
                <p>
                    Maintenance Team
                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width:25%;">
                <a href="index.php"><img src="samurai.png" alt="Samurai" width="150" height="150" /></a>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul >
        <li id="li_0" >
            <label class="description" for="element_0">Insert into DB </label>
            <br/>
        </li>
        <li id="li_1" >
            <label class="description" for="element_1" name="id" >ID </label>
            <input type="text" name="id" />
        </li>
        <li id="li_2" >
            <label class="description" for="element_3">Date </label>
            <span>
                <input id="element_3_1" name="element_3_1" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text">
                / <label for="element_3_1">MM</label> 
            </span>
            <span>
                <input id="element_3_2" name="element_3_2" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text">
                / <label for="element_3_2">DD</label> 
            </span>
            <span>
                <input id="element_3_3" name="element_3_3" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text">
                <label for="element_3_3">YYYY</label> 
            </span>
            <span id="calendar_3"> <img id="cal_img_3" class="datepicker" src="calendar.gif" alt="Pick a date."> </span>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Calendar.setup({
                    inputField : "element_3_3",
                    baseField : "element_3",
                    displayArea : "calendar_3",
                    button : "cal_img_3",
                    ifFormat : "%B %e, %Y",
                    onSelect : selectDate
                });
            </script>
        </li>
        <li id="li_3" >
            <label class="description" for="element_2" name="refid" >Refid </label>
            <input type="text" name="refid" />
        </li>
        <li id="li_4" >
            <label class="description" for="element_4" name="classification" >Classification </label>
            <select name="classification">
                <option value="SECRET">SECRET</option>
                <option value="SECRET//NOFORN">SECRET//NOFORN</option>
                <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">CONFIDENTIAL</option>
                <option value="CONFIDENTIAL//NOFORN">CONFIDENTIAL//NOFORN</option>
                <option value="UNCLASSIFIED">UNCLASSIFIED</option>
                <option value="UNCLASSIFIED//FOR OFFICIAL USE ONLY">UNCLASSIFIED//FOR OFFICIAL USE ONLY</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li id="li_5" >
            <label class="description" for="element_5" name="origin" >Origin </label>
            <input type="text" name="origin" />
        </li>
        <li id="li_6" >
            <label class="description" for="element_6" name="destination" >Destination </label>
            <input type="text" name="destination" />
        </li>
        <li id="li_7" >
            <label class="description" for="element_7" name="header" >Header </label>
            <input type="text" name="header" />
        </li>
        <li id="li_8" >
            <label class="description" for="element_8" name="content" >Content </label>            <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="content"></textarea>
            <br/>
        </li>
        <input type="Submit" />
    </ul >
</form>
```

And anohter PHP that connects to my MySQL:

```
<?php

    $id = $_POST['element_1'];
    $date = $_POST['element_3_3'].'-'.$_POST['element_3_1'].'-'.$_POST['element_3_2'];
    $refid = $_POST['element_2'];
    $classification = $_POST['element_4'];
    $origin = $_POST['element_5'];
    $destination = $_POST['element_6'];
    $header = $_POST['element_7'];
    $content = $_POST['element_8']; 

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXXXX","XXXXXX");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Error connecting to mysql server:  ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("XXXXXX", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO emails (id, date, refid, classification, origin, destination, header, content)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[refid]','$_POST[classification]','$_POST[origin]','$_POST[destination]','$_POST[header]','$_POST[content]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

All other forms are working and I can add them, all except Date. Maybe because I add DAY / MONTH / YEAR as one string on wrong way.

Comment: the format of datetime should be _'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'_ you are only providing _YYYY-MM-DD_ change the field to _date_

Comment: You should read about SQL injections. Your form is very unsafe. Use prepared statements or if that's a step too far use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: It is very necessary, but off topic, to mention that you absolutely MUST escape your variables! As you're using `mysql_` methods, use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['variable'])` and you'll be good. Also, try to use `mysqli_` or `PDO` methods instead as well.

Comment: Obligatory: http://xkcd.com/327

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date() format when inserting into datetime in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you're reading POST variables twice, and the second time is the one that isn't working, but the one that you need to work (because it's the `INSERT` statement!):

At the top, you have this:

```
$id = $_POST['element_1'];
$date = $_POST['element_3_3'].'-'.$_POST['element_3_1'].'-'.$_POST['element_3_2'];
$refid = $_POST['element_2'];
```

...but then later you have this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO emails (id, date, refid, classification, origin, destination, header, content) VALUES
('$_POST[id]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[refid]','$_POST[classification]','$_POST[origin]','$_POST[destination]','$_POST[header]','$_POST[content]')";
```

Your form is setting the `name` attribute for things like `refid`, `classification` etc., but there is no value coming from the form for the POST element `date`, so you're getting nothing, and so it's inserting nothing. I'm guessing you were hoping to use the concatenated value you're putting in `$date` in the second line, but you're not using `$date` in the insert statement, but `$_POST[date]`, which does not exist.

You might find it will improve if you use the variables you populate at the top rather than POST variables in the `INSERT` statement, but I suggest you only do that as a stop-gap while following the advice of others in comments! Your code as it stands needs quite a bit of bolstering and securing before it's ready for a live website.

Comment: The answer you want is to replace `$_POST[date]` with `$date` in the second example (the construction of the insert statement). That will help you get this example to work, but it won't make the code robust enough to run on a website. You'll need to pay a lot more attention to  resolving your SQL injection risks.

Comment: Rene's comment under your question is a good start! It's a lot of work to get to where you should be, but well worth it if you're going to be a web developer.

Answer (score 1):

Load jquery min and ui into your page with a CDN or host it.

Run date picker on the field you want and make sure it is in the format you want.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var pickerOpts = {
            dateFormat:"d MM, yy"
        }; 
        $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts);
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<label>Date</label><input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $row_config['date']; ?>">
```

Then update or insert

```
if ($_POST) {
$date = $post['date']; //escape this string
mysql_query("UPDATE config SET date = '$date'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Modify this method to fit your code. I utilize this to set a date site construction is ending. Hence I update, and print the value in the date field to show the admin what date it is set for, in case he wants to change it.

FOR YOUR CODE (havent tested, although filter is a function I use), this will handle everything in one page.

```
<?php
function filter($data) // for sql injection
{
   // normalize $data because of get_magic_quotes_gpc
   $dataNeedsStripSlashes = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
   if ($dataNeedsStripSlashes) {
       $data = stripslashes($data);
   }
   // normalize $data because of whitespace on beginning and end
   $data = trim($data);
   // strip tags
   $data = strip_tags($data);
   // replace characters with their HTML entitites
   $data = htmlentities($data);
   // mysql escape string    
   $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
   return $data;
}

if ($POST) {

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXXXX","XXXXXX") or die("Could not connect to database! " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("XXXXXX");

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { // will escape and filter post data
        $post[$key] = filter($value);
    }

    $id = $post['element_1'];
    $date = $post['date']; // change this in the database to date varchar 50 or something
    $refid = $post['element_2'];
    $classification = $post['element_4'];
    $origin = $post['element_5'];
    $destination = $post['element_6'];
    $header = $post['element_7'];
    $content = $post['element_8']; 

    // we already posted so we dont have to repost data
    $sql="INSERT INTO emails (id, date, refid, classification, origin, destination, header, content) 
    VALUES ('$id','$date','$refid','$classification','$origin','$destination','$header','$content')";

    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var pickerOpts = {
        dateFormat:"d MM, yy"
    }; 
    $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="formname" id="formid"> <!-- impt to have action="" -->
<!-- add all your other elements here -->
<label>Date</label><input type="text" id="date" name="date">
<!-- buttons here -->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should I remove from my code, and where exactly to put yours.

Comment: alternatively you could take the php data and put it in insert.php as you have remove the `if($post){}` around the data.

Comment: All in one... if you want. otherwise you can modify it using my previous comment to do two