# Fast way in PHP to check if a value is in MySQL datetime format?

Tags: php, string

Does anyone know if there is a built in or quick function to check if a string is a MySQL datetime format? Here is an example:

```
2038-01-19 03:14:07
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql See php [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation. Example: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Answer (score 15):

You can try `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2038-01-19 03:14:07')` and see if it returns false. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: This is better than regex which I was about to suggest, thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work for dates missing a space between day and hour. ie. 2021-10-0603:58:00. PHP interprets this well but MySQL does not. MySQL converts it to 2021-10-07 00:00:00.

Comment: This doesn't work for strings like '0001-11-11 00:00:00', this method approves them as appropriate, while mysql will give you an error here.

Answer (score 12):

I loved the answer by epicdev, however, the class seems to only validate the format, a date like 2015-18-39 is still valid for it and is converted to 2016-07-09 instead of rejecting the invalid day/month
A slight change to it is to double check that the date parsed is still the same as the date entered.

function proposed by glavic at gmail dot com on php.net documentation

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

<sup>*function was copied from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332) or [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205)*</sup>

Comment: This worked for me. Not sure if it is the same with **OP** @102635

Comment: For the same reason at I stated in epicdev's answer this doesn't work for dates missing the space between the day and hour. I haven't tested anything else.

Comment: @Rooster242 Can you put an example? I don't understand the issue.
I tested this function with '2021-10-0603:58:00' and I got false as expected