# Converting datetime from SQL to string in PHP

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I have an SQL database table which contains a column which holds data of datetime format. Now, after getting the values of this row, I need to convert the datettime to a readable string, but I'm unable to do this. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($handle, "SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE id=$id");

while($curr = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // CONVERT $curr['datetimefield'] TO STRING
    // echo $strong-format-of-datetime;
}
```

The conversion part is what I'm stuck at. If anybody could help with this, I'd be really grateful.

Thank You.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql

it might help you with what you are looking for

Comment: DATE-TIME returns readable string, are you looking to change the order?

Answer (score 5):

You can change format what you want: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
$date = strtotime($curr['datetimefield']);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can convert date while SQL query: `STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y')`