# Storing a date in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I use this code in php to generate the current date/time

```
$time = date("m.d G:i:s T Y");
```

Now i need to store the value in `time` in mysql table

However it is show as illegal in my table , that is as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

The datatype used by my column is `datetime`

Thanks for helping me fix it:)

Answer (score 1):

You try like this

```
$time = date("Y:m:d H:i:s");
```

Because mysql datetime  must be in `YYYY-MM-DD H:I:S` format.. Otherwise the data inserted in that field will be `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

You can refer to these links for more reference

[Link 1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql?rq=1)

Comment: i need to store the Timezone abbreviation as well , that's why there is a `T` in the command

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($time));
```

Comment: i need to store the Timezone abbreviation as well , that's why there is a T in the command –

Comment: Then store that abbreviation in another column.
Or store it all as a varchar.

Comment: Its not possible to store it in same column...i don't mind changing the data type