# Values not saving in the MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to save the utm parameters and other values in mysql using PHP, but the values are not savind in the database.

I already echo each variables and the values are present. What's wrong with the query? Why the values are not saving in the database?

And how to insert the date? I mean, I want to insert/save the date when the values are inserted.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != ""){
    $customer_fname = isset($_POST['customer_fname']) ? $_POST['customer_fname'] : '';
    $customer_sname = isset($_POST['customer_sname']) ? $_POST['customer_sname'] : '';
    $customer_email = isset($_POST['customer_email']) ? $_POST['customer_email'] : '';
    $customer_mobile = isset($_POST['customer_mobile']) ? $_POST['customer_mobile'] : '';
    $utm_source = isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '';
    $utm_medium = isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : '';
    $utm_campaign = isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : '';
    $utm_content = isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : '';
    $referer_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $base_url = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO utm_param(customer_fname,customer_sname,
                                                   customer_email,customer_mobile,
                                                   utm_source,utm_medium,
                                                   utm_campaign,utm_content,
                                                   referer_url,base_url,date_inserted)
            VALUES('".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_fname)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_sname)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_email)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_mobile)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_source)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_medium)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_campaign)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_content)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($referer_url)."',
                   '".$conn->real_escape_string($base_url)."')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result){
        echo "row inserted\n";
    } else {
        echo '<br/>aaa';
    }
}
```

Comment: run the query on database editor and check the error or warning if any

Comment: Where is $conn coming from? You may be able to turn up a debug level to see what error occurs on ELSE. e.g. $conn->getError(); or similar. You may also want to use ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL) for development...

Comment: which one is the date field in above code...

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi, i didn't put the date field yet since I don't know how to insert in when the other values are inserted

Comment: @JI-Web $conn is the db connection only. I already use the `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ` but the error displayed only is `Error`

Comment: you can add field name and values, otherwise set default value to the column in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query, you miss the `date_inserted` value. If it has to be "NOT NULL", the query will fail.

To insert a date in DB, I suggest you see this link : [PHP date() format when inserting into datetime in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql).

So following the link above, to save the date of when the values where inserted, you'll have to do something like this :

```
// set the value
$date_inserted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//insert the values
$sql = "INSERT INTO utm_param(
    customer_fname,
    customer_sname,
    customer_email,
    customer_mobile,
    utm_source,
    utm_medium,
    utm_campaign,
    utm_content,
    referer_url,
    base_url,
    date_inserted
) VALUES(
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_fname)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_sname)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_email)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($customer_mobile)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_source)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_medium)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_campaign)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($utm_content)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($referer_url)."',
    '".$conn->real_escape_string($base_url)."',
    '".$date_inserted."'
);";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how to save the date inserted automatically? I mean, I want to save the date inserted when the values are inserted

Comment: @User014019 I edited my answer to insert the current datetime (actually, the datetime when the values are insert). Also, your `date_inserted` MySQL field has to be "DATETIME" type.

Comment: it's working now. thanks!