# What's wrong with my sql script? Cannot save current time for timestamps

Tags: php

The result is always `0000-00-00 00:00:00` everytime I post a feed

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO feed ( feed, created, user_id_fk) VALUES (:feed,:created,:user_id)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("feed", $feed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam("user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $created = time();
        $stmt->bindParam("created", $created, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: did you tried `echo`ing the `created` variable. I you should use `date()` instead of `time()` because according to PHP manual `time()` returns the _seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)_.

Comment: I believe your parameters in the `$stmt->bindParam()` require `:` as well, so `$stmt->bindParam(":feed", $feed, PDO::PARAM_STR);`, etc.

Comment: @Rasclatt but the feed and user_id is already working. Only the created shows 0000...

Comment: perhaps just: `$sql = "INSERT INTO feed ( feed, created, user_id_fk) VALUES (:feed,NOW(),:user_id)";` no binding required

Comment: What's the field type of the created column?  Hunch is it's a date time column rather than a unix time stamp.  If so see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql and you'll need to bind as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use `date()` instead of `time()`. I would like to suggest something like this to you.

```
//Get time
date_default_timezone_set("America/Adak"); //Set the correct time zone here.
$created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //Output looks like 2001-03-10 17:16:18

$sql = "INSERT INTO feed ( feed, created, user_id_fk) VALUES (:feed,:created,:user_id)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":feed", $feed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
        $stmt->bindParam(":created", $created, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
```

If you need to know the supported time zones then here is the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php)

Comment: In table or the variable ?

Comment: ah ok, Glad to help