# php date format does not insert time in database

Tags: php, mysql, date, yii2

I am using the date format in my `php controller` like

`$meter->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

But the output I am getting is `2017-11-29 00:00:00`

I have also checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215359/8919244).

**Update 1**

I am inserting some data via excel file.

```
foreach($final_data as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key <= $header_index) continue;
        $meter = new Meters;

        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            $v = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($v));
            if(isset($fieldSet[0]['meter_msn']) && $fieldSet[0]['meter_msn']==$k){
                $meter->meter_msn =$v."";
                // echo $v.", ";
            }

            if(isset($fieldSet[0]['description']) && $fieldSet[0]['description']==$k){
                $meter->description = $v;
            }

            if (isset($fieldSet[0]['status']) && $fieldSet[0]['status'] == $k) {
                $meter->status = $v;
            }

            if (isset($fieldSet[0]['meter_status']) && $fieldSet[0]['meter_status'] == $k) {
                $meter->meter_status = $v;
            }

            if (isset($fieldSet[0]['historic']) && $fieldSet[0]['historic'] == $k) {
                $meter->historic = $v;
            }

        }
        $meter->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if($meter->save())
            $ok_count++;
        else
            $status_arr[] = $meter->errors;

    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is your table `created_at` field's data type?

Comment: More info please. What's your input? What's your insert statement? Is anything else inserted in your database? Be as precise as you can be and give as much info as you can.

Comment: @BabakBandpey it's `datetime` in database

Comment: @SheperdOfFire kindly check my `update 1`

Comment: dump the `$meter` before save. What do you get?

Comment: @MrFaisal what's the question?

Comment: @BabakBandpey while dumping it I am getting `["created_at"]=> string(19) "2017-11-29 12:49:28" `

Comment: and can you confirm that this date is saved into the table?

Comment: Yes it's saving into the table

Comment: Then it is after you select it that it changes the time part into 0s?

Comment: Yes after insertion the time part is shown in `0s`

Comment: The time in the table is saved as "2017-11-29 12:49:28" but when selected it shows "2017-11-29 00:00:00"? just to be sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160062/discussion-between-mr-faisal-and-babak-bandpey).

Comment: Why don't you use Timestamp behaviour to insert created and updated at time into database?

Comment: i added an answer please see if it helps you out

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you so other having the same problem also get the benefit

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I will surely check into it and get back to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the datatype for date fields like `created_at` and `update_at` as `int` and use `TimestampBehaviour` in your model.

By default, `TimestampBehavior` will fill the `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes with the current `timestamp` when the associated `AR` object is being `inserted`. it will fill the `updated_at` attribute with the `timestamp` when the `AR` object is being `updated`. The `timestamp` value is obtained by `time()` and whenever and where ever you want to show the date you can format it using php's `date()` function no need to make it complex when the framework itself can do it via conventional approach.

You might have to make little change for renaming the columns to `created_at` and `updated_at` and then include the `TimestampBehaviour` like below in your model.

use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

```
 public function behaviors() {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }
```

Or if you want to use the column names as is you can use the following approach to map you field names

```
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'create_time',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'update_time',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

`TimestampBehavior` also provides a method named `touch()` that allows you to assign the current `timestamp` to the specified `attribute(s)` and save them to the database. For example,

```
$model->touch('creation_time');
```

Comment: is ko b accept ker lo @MrFaisal , itna english solution diya tha