# PHP date and time to Mysql datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

Im trying to get the current time in PHP using 
    `$sTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`
     and store it in a mysql table in a **datetime** column like:
 `$sTQuery = "INSERT INTO Actions(UserID, StartDuration) VALUES ('$UserID' , '$sTime')";`

The date echos as expected but in the table it just shows 0000-00-00 00:00:0.

I have tried using now() in the query but still get 0000-00-00 00:00:0 in the table.

Edit: In the mysql table the column the date and time is to be stored in is a **datetime**

Comment: what's the column type or table schema? Also, read about PDO or at least about SQL Injection

Comment: if you use `now()`, make sure to use that without quotes. Although depending on the column type, you may need a different function like `current_timestamp()`.

Comment: Have you looked what has been stored in the database? This is not the same as a date 'print' or 'echo'.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the column is a datetime. I know about SQL injection, just trying to get basic implementation sorted first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date() format when inserting into datetime in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware in the table it just appears as 0000-00-00 00:00:0 the echo shows the correct date and time

Comment: Why is the last zero in `0000-00-00 00:00:0` missing?

Comment: @AbhigyanTiwari the suggested answer there doesn't represent the same issues as here as the format i have been using in date() is the same format as the answer

Comment: @KIKOSoftware just a typo sorry, it is there on the table

Comment: @GolezTrol is current_timestamp() used in the same way as now in the query?

Comment: Based on the code in your question (which is vulnerable to sql injection), this is not possible. The problem lies elsewhere in your code, but you are not providing enough information. Please edit your question with the create table statement, and the `SELECT` query you are testing with, so we can try to reproduce the problem. Also provide the result to `SELECT NOW()`.

Comment: @rlanvin I'm kind of new to php and mysql and understand a bit of injection but on my site there isn't a place for a user to enter any information, my code simply gathers information in the background like about the computer, pages on they visit and time on the site, so how can they inject if there is no where for them to type?

Comment: @sammcd75 If you are new it would be wise to simply follow the best practices, they exist for a reason. Even if you think it's not exploitable *right now*, one day you will reuse this piece of code somewhere else, forget that your query is vulnerable... and boom. Just don't build SQL queries like this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this query...
This contains DateTime value by `now()` as per your need.

```
$sTQuery = "INSERT INTO Actions(UserID, StartDuration) VALUES ('$UserID' ,now())";
```

Comment: Tried this and in the mysql table the entry is still 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: what? what your column data type.

Comment: the column is a datetime

Comment: so you tried the direct query on MySQL without PHP is this query give the same result there too?

Comment: Make your column type as `TIMESTAMP` instead on `DateTime` may this can solve your issue.

Comment: I tried doing the query on mysql directly and it worked so that must suggest that the error is in the php somewhere.

Comment: Yes, absolutely you tried the above-commented suggestion?