# MySql not allow to insert full date in datetime field in version 5.7.*

Tags: mysql

Just want to change this via configuration only. without change my query

Current SQL_MODE is

**`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`**

I have one table dummy_test and there is one field name created_at

created_at    =>      datetime(NULL)

When i perform below query

```
insert into dummy_test values('2018-08-14 05:38:11 pm')
```

ITs give me an error

**Error in query (1292): Incorrect datetime value: '2018-08-14 05:38:11 pm' for column 'created_at' at row 1**

It's working fine with

```
insert into dummy_test values('2018-08-14 05:38:11')
```

Comment: times are stored in 24hour notation. so 5:38:11 should be 17:38:11, thus pm is no longer necessary.

Comment: Yes you right, is there any solution with sql_mode or directly set 24 hours time when i pass above query.

Answer (score 2):

Per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes TIME values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in 'D HH:MM:SS' format. You can also use one of the following “relaxed” syntaxes: 'HH:MM:SS', 'HH:MM', 'D HH:MM', 'D HH', or 'SS'. Here D represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.
> - As a string with no delimiters in 'HHMMSS' format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, '101112' is understood as '10:11:12', but '109712' is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part) and becomes '00:00:00'.
> - As a number in HHMMSS format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, 101112 is understood as '10:11:12'. The following alternative formats are also understood: SS, MMSS, or HHMMSS.

So you'll have to use 24-hour time when sending to MySQL. If you're passing the date/time via PHP, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215354/php-date-format-when-inserting-into-datetime-in-mysql) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function
ie..  `insert into dummy_test values(STR_TO_DATE('2018-08-14 05:38:11 PM', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p'))`

If you want, you can add a "BeforeInsert" table trigger to intercept and convert those values.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable replay but i dont want change in sql queries because my project is working on. I just want to change it by sql configuration

Comment: Also, the format string provided doesn't match the formatted date (the format string uses slashes for the date, and `%y` matches a 2-digit year instead of a 4-digit one).